# angular2 default date pipe , number pipe and currency pipe not working with null values

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I have date and amount fields that can be null in form submission. When I display these fields in details page with date and amount(0.00) using filters it throws
 Invalid argument '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for pipe 'DatePipe' and  Invalid argument '0.00' for pipe 'Number'

Comment: obviously how would angular2 convert null value to some number or date?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual form I can't help you debug it, but just a not about filters and pipes, they convert existing values.

I think your best bet is to make sure you have defaults for your date and whatever other amount you are filtering.

For example your date would default to today, and amount to zero, then the filter should work.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid this by using *ngIf:

Example:

[image: Look at the code on the image]